# Phonegap - email html form content

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I have the below HTML code which basically sends mail on click of submit button

```
 <form action="mailto:xxx@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="Name"><br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <input type="text" name="mail" value="E-Mail"><br>
        Comment:<br>
        <input type="text" name="comment" value="Comments" size="50"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

when I hit the submit button in the phonegap application I get the below in the logcat.

```
DroidGap: GapViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-10 Description=net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME URL=mailto:xxx@gmail.com?body=name%3Dyour%20name%0D%0Amail%3Dxxx%40gmail.com%0D%0Acomment%3Dyour%20comment%0D%0A
```

I am not able to resolve this issue. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use email composer Plugins to send email.

SMSComposer plugin